# Unit test Dagger Fragments with FragmentScenario

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, dagger-2, android-fragmentscenario

I am trying to test fragment interactions using the Android Jetpack Navigation Component and the fragment-testing library.
My app is using java + Dagger2 as DI.

To test the navigation I have created a JUnit test:

```
    @Test
    public void testNavigationToLoginFragment() {
        // Create a mock NavController
        NavController mockNavController = mock(NavController.class);

        // Create a graphical FragmentScenario for the Intro Fragment
        FragmentScenario<IntroFragment> introFragmentScenario = FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(IntroFragment.class);

        // Set the NavController property on the fragment
        introFragmentScenario.onFragment(fragment ->
                Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), mockNavController)
        );

        // Verify that performing a click prompts the correct Navigation action
        onView(withId(R.id.button_login)).perform(click());
        verify(mockNavController).navigate(R.id.action_intro_fragment_to_login_fragment);
    }
```

Whenever I run the test I get following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class<XXX>
```

How can I inject my fragment there? Is it possible to use DaggerFragments with `FragmentScenario`?

**IntroFragment**

```
public class IntroFragment extends DaggerFragment{
    @Inject
    CreateQuoteRecyclerViewAdapter createQuoteRecyclerViewAdapter;

    @Inject
    public ViewModelProvider.Factory factory;

    @inject 
    public MyViewModel viewModel;
    .....

}
```

**MyViewModel.java**

```
class CreateOrSignInViewModel extends BaseViewModel() {
  @Inject
  public  CreateOrSignInBindingState state;


 ......
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution  for this?

Comment: show us your fragment code

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher please check the update.

Answer (score 4):

Declare following function within test class:

```
@Config(application = TestApp::class)
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LooperMode(LooperMode.Mode.PAUSED)
class MyFragmentTest {

    private val createQuoteRecyclerViewAdapter: CreateQuoteRecyclerViewAdapter = mock()
    private val viewModel: MyViewModel = mock()

    private fun launchFragment(): FragmentScenario<MyFragment> {
      return launchFragmentInContainer(factory = object : FragmentFactory() {
        override fun instantiate(classLoader: ClassLoader, className: String): Fragment {
          return MyFragment().apply {
            createQuoteRecyclerViewAdapter = this@MyFragmentTest.createQuoteRecyclerViewAdapter
            viewModel = this@MyFragmentTest.viewModel
            // assign other deps here as per your needs
          }
        }
      }, themeResId = R.style.AppTheme)
    }

}
```

Where `TestApp` is declared as such:

```
    class TestApp : Application()
```

This might be needed in order to refrain from error, which will happen in your custom application class's `onCreate()` method, where Dagger tree is being constructed.

After having this setup you can start writing your unit test:

```
@Test
fun `navigation to login screen is correctly performed`() {
    val navController: NavController = mock()

    val scenario = launchFragment()
    scenario.onFragment {
        Navigation.setViewNavController(it.requireView(), navController)
    }

    onView(withId(R.id.button_login)).perform(click())
    verify(mockNavController).navigate(R.id.action_intro_fragment_to_login_fragment)
}
```